# 翻訳が不自然: 回答が「承認された」とはどういう意味ですか?

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

> 回答:の承認は、質問に対して完全な回答が得られたという決定的で最終的な表明ではありません。単に、作成者が個人的に満足する回答を得たということを意味するだけで、すべてのユーザーが戻ってきて回答を承認することや、承認したユーザーが後で新しくより良い回答が投稿されたときに承認された回答を変更しないとオブジェクトいうことを意味するわけではありません。

原文   
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
>   statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that
>   worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to
>   accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the
>   accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

修正案

回答の承認は、質問に対して完全な回答が得られたという決定的で最終的な表明ではありません。単に、作成者が個人的に満足する回答を得たということを意味するだけであって、すべてのユーザーが回答を承認するわけではなく、後で新しくより良い回答が投稿されたときに、承認したユーザーが承認された回答を変更するとは限りません。

Answer (score 2):

適用済みです：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

> 回答の承認は、質問に対して完全な回答が得られたという決定的で最終的な表明ではありません。単に、作成者が個人的に満足する回答を得たということを意味するだけであって、すべてのユーザーが回答を承認するわけではなく、後で新しくより良い回答が投稿されたときに、承認したユーザーが承認された回答を変更するとは限りません。